# How to execute multiple api calls around 300 simultaneously in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

We have a requirement in which we should fetch multiple records each one in single api. Then insert that record in local DB (sqlite). Let say we have to make around 300 api calls simultaneously as each record is independent. How can we achieve this using isolate groups in flutter.

We tried to implement this using flutter isolate, but we ended up with some errors.

Can we use http calls in isolate?
Can we use sqlite CRUD operations in flutter isolate ?

I would appreciate and thanks in advance if some one can help out here a solution with working example.

Comment: First of all, why do you need to parallelize api call? Isn't concurrency of async suffisant?

Comment: You can do whatever you want in an isolate (HTTP API calls, SQFLite operations, etc.)

You write you have errors, can you provide source code and errors?